# max number of lines in a text file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio to write a lot of data to a file. It's going to be running for a long time so I just want to make sure that there isn't going to run out of space or anything like that. Does anybody know?

Comment: Do you mean VS itself writing the file, or a program you've written with VS writing the file? If the latter, which language did you use/are you using?

Comment: Its a program I've written in VS in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain it's still there, but I seem to recall at one time running into problems writing more than 2 Gig files. Two points though: 1) I haven't used C# and/or .NET a huge amount, so it may have been just my ignorance of how to use it well, and 2) that was a while back, so even assuming it was really a limitation then, it *may* have been fixed since.

Comment: I guess I'll take my chances. I don't think I'm going to be writing 2GB of text. Thanks!